# Does the display serve protocol (Wayland or X11) affect the terminal capabilities?

Tags: terminal, x11, wayland, display-server

I wonder whether the display server protocol that my system uses can affect some capabilities in my terminal, such as

1. Clipboard interaction.
2. Rendering images on terminal, etc...

Since the primary role of a display server protocol is to manage graphical user interfaces, I am unsure if it affects the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how your terminal emulator is written. If it's a classical X11 client, and runs under Wayland through XWayland, it really shouldn't make a difference. (Although there is a bit of a difference in the kinds of clipboards that X11 has . Not an often observed fact to begin with...)

If it's more modern and does have a Wayland backend, then it might make a mistake or omit a feature in one of these backends, leading to functional differences. But I don't see why someone would do that.